# Replacing values in Pandas Dataframe Column with new text and ascending number, using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, group-by

Python beginner here. I have values in a Pandas Dataframe that I would like to change to a new value. Also, I then want to apply an ascending value at the end of the new text. My zone column below needs to be changed to still group by zone.

**This is an example of how my Dataframe currently looks**:

| value | section | zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 25 |
| 2 | red | 25 |
| 3 | grey | 28 |
| 4 | blue | 35 |
| 5 | yellow | 35 |
| 6 | yellow | 35 |
| 7 | blue | 50 |
| 8 | green | 50 |

**This is the changes in the 'zone' column I would like to make:**

| value | section | zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | Zone1 |
| 2 | red | Zone1 |
| 3 | grey | Zone2 |
| 4 | blue | Zone3 |
| 5 | yellow | Zone3 |
| 6 | yellow | Zone3 |
| 7 | blue | Zone4 |
| 8 | green | Zone4 |

I'm not quite sure how to handle this problem. I'm assuming I need to use some sort of `dataframe.replace()`. I am not too skilled with python yet, so I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Do you have all possible numerical values of the zone column?

Comment: @1001pepi so this is just a snippet of the actual total dataframe of data. The dataset is much larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['zone'] = 'Zone' + (df.groupby('zone').ngroup() + 1).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   value section   zone
0      1     red  Zone1
1      2     red  Zone1
2      3    grey  Zone2
3      4    blue  Zone3
4      5  yellow  Zone3
5      6  yellow  Zone3
6      7    blue  Zone4
7      8   green  Zone4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.rank` with the dense method to rank your zones. Here we cast to int before casting to string because otherwise the ranks are given with decimal points.

```
df["zone2"] = "zone" + df.zone.rank(method="dense").astype("int").astype("str")
```